# Elegant mutex on/off switch for functions?

Tags: c++, templates, mutex

Can you think of an **elegant** way to create (member-)functions with an optional mutex locker? Let's ignore macros, for obvious reasons.

Of course, the easy way to go about it is by having two functions:

```
int getIndex() const    { std::lock_guard m( mtx ); return nm_getIndex(); }
int nm_getIndex() const { return _index; }
```

This creates efficient code, but it relies on code duplication. Basically, you'll end up with having most function declarations twice.

Another way would be turning them into template functions. The boolean template argument would function as the "en-/disabler". You could then call the function like this:

```
auto index = getIndex< NoMutex >();
```

whenever using the function internally (and locking the mutex otherwise). The problem here is to make sure that the mutex is unlocked even when an exception is thrown. That is, you can't simply use something like

```
if constexpr( MutexOn == true ) {
    mutex.lock();
}
do some stuff;
if constexpr( MutexOn == true ) {
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

The only thing I can currently think of is building a class around the mutex and putting it into a union. The class could then either "play the lock_guard" or do nothing. While I'm pretty sure that this would be optimized properly in release code, it still looks cumbersome and inflexible.
Therefore, I'm wondering if you can think of something better?

Thanks!

Comment: Of course there's the obvious template specialization method but that leads to multiple methods for 1 action as you said so yourself.

Comment: The "unique ptr to lock guard" approach is about the same as the unionionized version, but it adds the memory allocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach I can think of is:

1. Create a noop lock_guard class.
2. Make a template function that always use a lock guard of a type specified as template parameter.
3. When you want a non/blocking version of a function you can pass in the noop guard

For instance:

```
template<typename Guard>
int getIndex<Guard>() const    { Guard m( lock ); return nm_getIndex(); }

class NoopLockGuard ; //dummy class. it does absolutely nothing
int i = getIndex<NoopLockGuard>()
int j = getIndex<std::lock_guard>()
```

The compiler should be able to optimize the version with `NoopLockGuard` such that it would incur in minimal or zero performance penalty.

Comment: Thanks, that looks nice indeed. You can even pass other lock guards, like scoped locks, etc. :-)